# symfony 2 swiftmailer Cannot send message without a sender address

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

Trying to configure SwiftMailer to send messages with gmail.

Here is my configuration:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    host:      ~
    username:  username@gmail.com
    password:  password
```

And my controller action:

```
     public function registerAction(Request $request) {
                    $message = new \Swift_Message();                    
                            $message::newInstance()
                              ->setFrom('username@gmail.com')
                            ->setSubject('ssssssss')                            
                            ->setTo(array('username@gmail.com'))
                            ->setBody(
                                    'text is going here');       
                            $res = $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
}
```

And when I execute it:

**Cannot send message without a sender address
500 Internal Server Error - Swift_TransportException**

```
Stack Trace
in /var/www/local/symfony/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php at line 164   
        }
        if (!$reversePath = $this->_getReversePath($message)) {
            throw new Swift_TransportException(
                'Cannot send message without a sender address'
                );
        }
```

Comment: see my updated answer and accept if this way it works for you. the static call is the problem and not necessary :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you should pass the parameters directly to the Message constructor.

**Swift/Message**

```
public function __construct($subject = null, $body = null, $contentType = null, $charset = null) {
   // ...
}

public static function newInstance($subject = null, $body = null, $contentType = null, $charset = null)
{
    return new self($subject, $body, $contentType, $charset);
}
```

**Solution1**

```
$message = new Message();    
$message            
    ->setFrom('username@gmail.com')  // no static $message::newInstance() call here
    ->setSubject('ssssssss')                            
    ->setTo(array('username@gmail.com'))
    ->setBody('text is going here');
```

**Solution2**

```
$message = new Message('ssssss','text is going here');
$message        
    ->setTo(array('username@gmail.com'))
    ->setFrom('username@gmail.com');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Accidentally, solved it myself. My Message object was empty and didn't got any properties, I added using setters(From,Subject,To, etc.). The problem, is that I'm trying to access static (newInstance) from object. Actually, this variant is also works (why?), if I add one more assignment

$message = $message::newInstance(); $message->set......

Comment: please see my updated answer for all information - should be acceptable right? the static call to newInstance() returned an object but you did not set this object to $message. therefore you tried to send the empty Message object you created one line above!